# solve equation by explain n*n matrix or equation team

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I want to **solve n equation which has n root with Gauss-Elimination Method**. I indicated root formulation and methodology in picture. But I don't know that how can I do this. Should I explain **n*n matrix**? Or should I explain **equation team like picture's top**? Thanks for help.
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. What does _explain n*n matrix_ and _equation team_ mean? But more importantly: is your question about the Wolfram Mathematica software that this site is about? If not, your question is off topic. Try, e.g., http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If your goal is to solve such an equation, look at LinearSolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[a[n__]] := Subscript[a, n];
Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n];
Format[c[n_]] := Subscript[c, n];

coef[n_Integer?Positive] := Array[a, {n, n}];

var[n_Integer?Positive] := Array[x, n];

val[n_Integer?Positive] := Array[c, n];

eqns[n_Integer?Positive] := Thread[coef[n].var[n] == val[n]];
```

For example, with `n == 3`

```
n = 3;

eqns[n] // Column
```

[image]

```
(sol[n_] = Solve[eqns[n], var[n]][[1]] // Simplify) // Column
```

[image]

Verifying that `sol` satisfies `eqns`

```
And @@ (eqns[n] /. sol[n] // Simplify)

(* True *)
```

Alternatively, [`LinearSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) produces the same results

```
(var[n] /. sol[n]) == LinearSolve[coef[n], val[n]] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Bob Hanlon Thank you so much!